# Multiple VueJS TypeScript projects with a common library

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I'm building two VueJS applications in TypeScript, one is a client for the public to use, and the other is an admin tool the only I can use to edit the data displayed on the client. I'm using vue-cli and running a simple npm run serve to build and test my applications.

I'm duplicating A LOT of code and I'd like to move my typescript models and services files to a common library that can be accessed by both projects but I can't seem to figure out how to set this up.  I've seen only a couple TypeScript common library examples online but none of them match my exact situation and I can't seem to translate them to the VueJS world.

I'd rather not go the NPM package route since that seems like overkill for something this simple.

Comment: The change you want not *that* simple so NPM package isn't really an overkill. It shouldn't really be real NPM package, could be a fake one from git repo. A suitable way to handle this is a monorepo. This really depends on how projects are structured, which isn't described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to cobble together a solution using [this persons blog post](https://dev.to/hamishclulee/one-build-system-multiple-vue-apps-shared-components-283d).  It took me forever to figure out how to manage it though.

One problem I had was with the way this person was using the config.plugin('html) call in their chainWebpack config since my file layout wasn't the same as theirs. I now officially have 2 vuejs typescript projects sharing references with a third typescript project without having to build an NPM package.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would recommend following Occam's Razor and look into a re-architecture, rather than creating a common library for just two applications (as you said, an npm package is overkill). Build your admin application into the public client, but keep it behind secret credentials, and even only accessible from a route only you know about.

Comment: I thought about doing this at first but the code base felt too heavy with too many role checks in random places.  Whether or not to hide a button depending on logged in status just felt exhausting to me.  Plus I'm using a lot of dependencies in the admin tool that I'm not using in the client. Combining them all would blow up my initial payload size for the client with things that wont even be used by anyone but me.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend following [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/install-npm-packages-from-gitgithub) documentation on using an git repo as an NPM package. That way you can get the use of a TypeScript library, the clean code practice of using NPM, all while staying away from the NPM registry

Comment: That feels super clunky for development purposes. I'm currently building everything in one spot. If I were to set it up like this would I need to check in code from my common project, then do an npm update to get latest every time I made a change to common? It baffles me that there's no simpler way to share code across VueJS Typescript projects. I feel like this would make sense if my common library was already finished, but since it's in active development it feels like a lot of extra steps for something that's been common in software development for ages.